# Parse Chinese characters with URLEncodedUtils in Java

Tags: java, solr, special-characters, url-encoding

I have a uri like

```
http://localhost/?name=foo&value=bar
```

And I use

```
org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(URI uri, String encoding)
```

to get a list of NameValuePairs, and it works nicely. But now I have need also the possibility to parse  Chinese charecters, e.g.:

```
http://localhost/?name=生产者&value=单车
```

But URLEncodedUtilsparse fails to parse these characters correctly. How can I retrieve them and get a list of NameValuePairs again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
String query1 = URLEncoder.encode("生产者", "UTF-8");
String query2 = URLEncoder.encode("单车", "UTF-8");
String url = "http://localhost/?name=" + query1 + "&value=" + query2;
```

Also check the [java.net.URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Comment: In this case the first encoding also replaces the = and & with %3D and %26 and then URLEncodedUtils.parse(...) does not work any more.

Comment: @MrLang:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Comment: This would work if I had the name and value strings separately. But my intention was to use URLEncodedUtils.parse() to retrieve them. But now guess I have to split the whole uri by myself (whithout URLEncodedUtils) and encode the names and values afterwards.

Comment: @MrLang: Yes that seems to the solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar situation. URLEncodedUtils must be used with StringEntity. UrlEncodedFormEntity is broken.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    URL);
List<NameValuePair> param_data = new ArrayList<>();
param_data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", [STRING_FOREIGN CHARS));

String s = URLEncodedUtils.format(param_data, java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(s, java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

postRequest.setEntity(entity);  // don't use postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param_data));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
..[snipped] do whatever you want with response
```